# How to redirect to other page with parameters in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I integrated the stripe with react now after successful payment I  want to redirect to another page

```
await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(CLIENT_SECRET, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
          billing_details: {
            name: name,
          },
        },
        receipt_email: username,
      })
      .then(async function(result) {
        if (result.paymentIntent) {
          const formData = new FormData();
          let date = new Date(result.paymentIntent.created * 1000);
          formData.append('productId', productId); // in this line everything is fine and productId is defined here
          formData.append('dateCreated', date);
          const savePaymentIntent = await axios
            .post(
              // backend url,
              formData,
              config,
            )
            .then(r => {
              console.log(r);
              if (r.status === 201) {
                self.setState({ isPaymentPending: true });
                history.push('/user/${productId}/product-detail'); //Issue is in this line productId is undefined in url 
              }
            })
            .catch(e => {
              console.log(e);
            });
        } else if (result.error) {
           // some error handling code
        }
      });
```

**history.push('/user/${productId}/product-detail');**

http://localhost:3000/user/$%productId%7D/product-detail

Whenever i am creating formData for backend productId is present there, but
In this line, after successful payment, it is redirected to the product-detail page but **productId** is undefined

Comment: Can you update your question to include how you've defined your routes and the component that you are expecting to be rendered on that specific path?

Comment: my code is working fine for redirecting and also it rendering the component but the issue is productId id is undefined thats why in url http://localhost:3000/user/$%productId%7D/product-detail
But in formData i am getting the productId
and what i think is issue is in history.push

Comment: Oh, are you simply saying that `productId` is undefined here in this code then? Where is it declared in this snippet?

Comment: i updated the code and see in formData productId is present but after getting successful response i think  i am doing some thing wrong is history.push

Comment: Oh, I see, you've a typo: `history.push('/user/${productId}/product-detail');` should be `history.push(\`/user/${productId}/product-detail\`);`. You are passing the string literal versus an interpolated string template. Voting to close as "Unreproducible or caused by typo".

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code.

```
              if (r.status === 201) {
                self.setState({ isPaymentPending: true });
                history.push('/user/${productId}/product-detail'); //Issue is in this line productId is undefined in url 
              }
```

Instead of an inverted comma there should be ` or add string using +

```
             if (r.status === 201) {
                self.setState({ isPaymentPending: true });
                history.push(`/user/${productId}/product-detail`); //Issue is in this line productId is undefined in url 
              }
```